# How to make a scatter plot with different variables

Tags: python

Let's say I have a equation `y=a*x`, where `a=[1,2,3,4]` and `x`,`y` each have a set of values.

I get that for a simple x vs y plot `plt.scatter(x,y)` is enough, but how can I make a scatter plot of x vs y for each a?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The function `plt.scatter`, as the name heavily implies, produces a scatter plot. Can you give some examples of the sort of input/output you might be expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a list of axis objects and then it will make a scatterplot to each of them.
I imported numpy in order to multiply the lists, which are now numpy arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 4])
y = np.array([4, 5, 2])
a = np.array([1, 5, 2])


#create the axis objects
fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, len(a))

for i in range(len(a)):
    axis[i].scatter(x, y * a[i])
```